# disable EJS caching in production

Tags: node.js, express, pug, template-engine, ejs

It seems like whenever my `process.NODE_ENV` is set to `production`, EJS templating engine will cache all my .html files. So any modifications in those files will not be displayed, unless server restarts.

```
app.engine('.html', require('ejs').__express);
```

Is there a way to disable caching template on express? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems like [this is set explicitly as part of `express`'s built-in code](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/e5ec966b2f068e935ea1b33374fac133dd06cdc8/lib/application.js#L117)

```
if (env === 'production') {
  this.enable('view cache');
}
```

This gets called by `app.init` which is called by `createApplication` which is the function that gets exported and what you probably are calling with `app = express()`. You can immediately disable the caching on your own:

```
app = express();
app.disable('view cache');
```