# stop ejs caching javascript variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I want to disable ejs cache

I saw I can use

```
ejs.clearCache()
```

but I have to have an instance of `ejs` for that, atm I am just using

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

so I don't know how to force clear the ejs cache ( ideally I will stop it caching altogether).

---

```
app.disable('view cache');
```

didn't work

Comment: posible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35375276/disable-ejs-caching-in-production

Comment: @jenilchristo express.disable('view cache');
didn't work

Answer (score 0):

try to pass the express to app by:

```
app = express();
app.disable('view cache');
```

if doesn't work check your code!!

for learning more read the [express](https://expressjs.com/) docs!