# Ejs variable persistence?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have an express route which filters the month of a blog post and returns the months:

```
router.get("/months", async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        let posts = await pool.query(`select *  from posts
        where MonthName(created_at) = '${req.query.month}'`)

        console.log(`select *  from posts
        where MonthName(created_at) = '${req.query.month}'`)

        let tags = await pool.query(`Select tagName from tags`) 

        filter = req.query.month

        res.render("index",{posts,tags,filter})
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

It returns the blog posts filter by the month. As you can see I am sending back a filter variable so that in my template I am display the header as in my `index.ejs` file:

```
<h2><%= filter %> Blogs</h2>
```

So that it shows up as April Blogs or whatever filter the user selected

Now the same template is also shated by the default index route:

```
router.get("/", async (req,res)=>{
    try{
        let rows = await pool.query(`Select userName as author, posts.* from posts 
                                    inner join users on users.id = posts.user_id`)

        let tags = await pool.query(`Select tagName from tags`)                            
        res.render("index",{posts:rows,tags:tags})
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
})
```

By default no filter is applied and a filter variable is not even sent.

Now, the `localhost:3000/months/?month=April` is perfectly as expected and shows only the blog from April.

But I was expected the `localhost:3000` route to throw an error because it is not passing the filter variable but it shows whatever month I selected in the previous route filter.

Only when I terminate the Nodejs server and try to go to the default route do I get:

> filter is not defined

But if I go to `localhost:3000/months/?month=April` and then go back to ``localhost:3000` it loads just fine with month April.

Is it not a good idea to share templates between different routes? How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template is getting cached on first invocation. You might try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35375300/3100284) to disable the view cache in express -

```
router.disable('view cache');
```

Another options is listed on the [ejs wiki](https://github.com/mde/ejs/wiki/Using-EJS-with-Express#view-options) -

```
router.set('view options', {cache: false});
```

or you might try disabling in ejs with the additional options parameter -

```
res.render("index",{posts:rows,tags:tags}, {cache: false})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare filter and pass a default value, otherwise your renderer will fail.

```
router.get("/months", async (req,res)=> {

    try {

        let dbQuery = `select *  from posts`;

        // handle when req.query.month is not passed.
        if (req.query.month) {
           dbQuery += ` where MonthName(created_at) = '${req.query.month}'`;
        }

        const posts = await pool.query(dbQuery);

        const dbQuery2 = 'Select tagName from tags';
        const tags = await pool.query(dbQuery2); 

        // declare filter here and assign '' when it's not passed request,
        // otherwise your render will fail.
        const filter = query.month ? query.month : '';

        return res.render("index", {posts, tags, filter});


    } catch(err){

       // pass error to your main error handler.
       return next(err);

    }

})
```

Further i would recommend organising your code better.

```
// your common shared logic
    async function logic({query, params, body}){

        const dbQuery = `select *  from posts`;
        const posts = await pool.query(dbQuery);
        return {posts};

    }


    function handler(req, res, next) {

           logic(req)
              .then((result) => {

                return res.render("index",result);

              })
              .catch(next);

    }

    // you can create separate handlers for each requests
    // and use the shared logic in handlers.

    router.get("/", handler);
    router.get("/months", handler);
```