# Obeserving EJS file modifications using browser refreshing

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have an EJS file which I'm rendering with the help of express.js using a code like `res.render("example", {})`.
However, the problem is when I modify and save the EJS file the results cannot be seen immediately by pressing the refresh key in the browser and I have to restart the node server in order to see new version of the file. But I remember in other projects that was not the case and pressing the refresh immediately reflected the changes in the browser. What am I missing here? I am using the latest version of EJS.

Comment: Are you using nodemon to start development server ?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35375276/disable-ejs-caching-in-production

Comment: No, just manually stopping the server and starting it again using `node server.js`

Comment: For development server better use nodemon and see this link -https://github.com/remy/nodemon#packagejson